# trying to send text from python script to cell number with smtplib.SMTP.sendmail()

Tags: python, sendmail, smtplib

I am trying to send a simple text message from a python script running on either windows or Linux to a T-Mobile phone number:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(my_username, my_password)
message = ("From: my_email@gmail.com\r\n" +
           "To: 123456789@tmomail.net\r\n" +
           'Subject: this is the body')
server.sendmail(from_addr='123456789',
                to_addrs='123456789@tmomail.net',
                msg=message)
```

I receive the text message on my phone, but there are consistently two spurious characters at end of the message (`" /"`):

```
"this is the body /"
```

I have tried many variations of message and it either doesn't go through at all, or the two characters are present.

Comment: did you check if it works correctly if you send directly from gmail using web browser? Maybe gmail add some information.

Comment: I did check from my Gmail account and it works as it should (no extra characters)

Comment: I can't test it but first I would send to my gmail account to see what it gets in email body. Frankly, I don't see why it should add ` /` at the end.

Comment: I've tried that as well and it comes through cleanly (no extra characters)

Comment: I tried sending to my email address instead of my cell phone and the message comes through cleanly.  Can someone who has T-Mobile please try this and let me know if they are getting the extra characters?